# Assigning values to IFTTT Maker "ingredient" variables from a Python 'request'

Tags: python-2.7, post, httprequest, iot, ifttt

According to [documentation available](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ifttt-connect-anything-maker-channel/) on the Web, it should be possible to invoke a IFTTT Maker recipe with

```
import requests
payload = "{ 'value1' : 'P', 'value2' : 'Q', 'value3' : 'R'}"
requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY", data=payload)
```

This successfully involves the recipe. But all of the ingredient values ('value1', etc.) are blank in the response.

The corresponding `curl` successfully sets the values:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"P","value2":"Q","value3":"R"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY
```

How do I supply a payload to the request that correctly assigns these values?

Comment: Are you asking about the response body? Why do you need the values to come back in the response body? These values are used as "ingredients" for the "action" part of the "applet."

Comment: @EricCochran: I mean in the IFTTT recipe's processing of the invocation. It acts as if the values are not provided.

Comment: So you're setting them as part of the action (like send Tweet), and they're empty when the action runs?

Comment: @EricCochran : Yes. And the corresponding curl (out of the same article) works fine.

Comment: I'm not a Python 2.7 user, but is it possible that your third line should have "json=" instead of "data="?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample in the linked article is wrong. The payload [should be a `dict`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) (not a string description of a `dict`):

```
payload = { 'value1' : 'P', 'value2' : 'Q', 'value3' : 'R'}
```